# Create site/subsite using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, site, sub-site, microsoft-graph

Is there any way to create site/sub-site using **Microsoft Graph API**?

I know I can do this using CSOM but I am interested in using Microsoft graph for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to Microsoft documentation**,

There is Read-only support for site resources ( and no ability to create new sites) using Microsoft graph.

**Source**: [Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0).

---

**Additional**:

I have read on GitHub (and tried also) that SharePoint Online site will be created automatically if you create a Office 365 group and assign the owners & members to the group.

**Source**: [O365 Group Creation Does Not Immediately Create Site Collection](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/970#issuecomment-419987286).

**Reference**: [Microsoft Graph - Create group](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]

Comment: Have you any information if there is a ticket in Microsoft for this task?

Comment: Check the updated answer for alternative. but there is no other way to create SP site directly.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.